# Apollo Server HAPI CORS prefetch not working

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, apollo-server

I have a huge issue with the `graphql-server-hapi` module I have to use.
Everything works until I have to request my API from a browser with CORS.

Here's the register configuration :

```
register : GraphQLServer.graphqlHapi,
options : {
    path : '/graphql',
    graphqlOptions : {
        schema : Schema,
        graphiql : true
    },
    route : {
        cors : true
    }
}
```

Everything is fine with the `POST` requests I run with Postman on localhost, but when I want to run an `OPTIONS` request (as the browser will do) I got a 404 with an error on Access-Control-Request-Method :

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "CORS error: Missing Access-Control-Request-Method header"
}
```

I searched everywhere but nobody seems to encounter this issue before me (?!).
The official documentation says the `cors : true` is enough to enable CORS...

I tried to manually add the `OPTIONS` method on the register options, without any effect.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have you tried `server.connection({ routes: { cors: true } });` wherever you create your server?

Comment: Yes of course : I put the `cors: true` in the connection definition and in the graphql register option. Although I wonder if there is a way to force graphql to accept the `OPTIONS` method so the CORS could work.

Comment: Silly question again, but when you made the `OPTIONS` request in postman did you actually include the `Access-Control-Request-Method` header with the request?

Comment: Yes it did not change anything because the problem is not in the client but on the server. I don't know how to specify the Options method in the graphql registration.

Comment: I am so stupid... I just had to create a new route in Hapi with the same path as GraphQL and the method 'OPTIONS' to handle the CORS...

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer! Consider posting your solution as an answer here to help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution !

This was so simple, I just had to add this :

```
server.route({
    method : 'OPTIONS',
    path : '/graphql',
    handler : (request, reply) => {
        reply({ ok : true })
            .header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST')
    }
})
```

By adding the manual `OPTIONS` management, it sends a 200 and the browser can send the POST request :)

Comment: Yeah I know, for a simple GraphQL API it's working fine and it's not recommended to mix REST and GraphQL inside the same API.

Comment: This comment unlocked a similar problem for me on Hapi v20. The cors:true allows cors to happen... but it doesn't "handle it for you" when you've got a client that's going to make a preflight request.